# How to set dock widget below widget

Tags: qt, qt4, dock, qt4.8, qtgui

I want to set dock widget at place below a widget as in figure

[image]

But when I am setting geometry as start point of Y to equivalent the gap size but it is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I think position of QDockWidget should be handled different way, then setting its geometry.

This example shows how QDockWidgets are positioned as you want + one more dock widget tabbed together with another one.

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    // Main window
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;
    window->setDockNestingEnabled(true);
    // Anything to add as central widget
    QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
    window->setCentralWidget(widget);

    // First dock in the left top corner
    QDockWidget *dockWidget = new QDockWidget("--- 1 ---");
    window->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dockWidget);

    // Second dock below first one
    QDockWidget *dockWidget2 = new QDockWidget("--- 2 ---");
    window->addDockWidget(Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea, dockWidget2);

    // Third in tab with second one
    QDockWidget *dockWidget3 = new QDockWidget("--- 3 ---");
    window->tabifyDockWidget(dockWidget2, dockWidget3);

    window->show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

[QMainWindow](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html) Has several functions how to handle spliting, moving or tabbing [QDockWidgets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html)

Comment: Nice example, able to demonstrate how to use Docks